# Expression for the median of a sum of half-Cauchy random variables

Tags: estimation, median, cauchy-distribution

This is a technical problem I encountered in research. Sorry if it reads simple for professional statisticians.

Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be iid standard Cauchy random variables. What estimate or exact formula exists for the median of $\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|$? For $n=1$, it can be worked out explicitly the median is $1$:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[X \leq t\right] = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^t\;  \frac{1}{1+x^2}\; dx = \frac{2}{\pi} \left.\arctan x \right|_{0}^t = \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan t. 
$$

What about $n>1$? Any suggestions?

Comment: Its pretty hopeless for $n=2$ to get analytic form $$Pr(X_1+X_2<t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(t-x)f(x) dx=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{t} \tan^{-1}(t-x)\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
Make the substitution $x=\tan(y)$ and you get
$$=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}(t)} \tan^{-1}\left[t-\tan(y)\right]dy$$  ..... not simple integral

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Can you give some more detail on what you are looking for? For example: Are you trying to *prove* something, so, e.g., an upper and/or lower bound would be useful? What size of $n$ are you concerned with? Or do, you want something asymptotic, like a growth rate? Sorry for so many questions. I generally agree with @probabilityislogic that it looks unlikely you'll get a nice closed-form expression for general $n$. :)

Comment: @cardinal: Thanks for the reply and clarification. I'm mostly concerned with how the median would grow with $n$. My simulations showed it's very roughly $n\log n$. I hope some rigorous analysis on this can be found.

Answer (score 3):

**One way to deduce the simulated $n\log(n)$ behavior is through truncation.**

Generally, for any distribution $F$ and $0\le \alpha\lt  1$ let $F_\alpha$ be truncated symmetrically in both tails so that for $F^{-1}(\alpha/2)\le x \le F^{-1}(1-\alpha/2),$

$$F_\alpha(x) = \min{\left(1, \frac{F(x) - \alpha/2}{1-\alpha}\right)}.$$

Let $E_\alpha$ be the expectation of $F_\alpha$ defined by

$$E_\alpha = \int_{\mathbb R} x\,\mathrm{d}F_\alpha(x).$$

Because the support of $F_\alpha$ is bounded, it has finite expectation and variance.  The Central Limit Theorem tells us that for sufficiently large sample sizes $n,$ the sum of $n$ *iid* random variables with $F_\alpha$ for their common distribution is approximately Normal with mean $n E_\alpha.$  This approximate Normality implies the *median* of the sum distribution also is approximately $n E_\alpha.$

Now, the median of a sum of independent variables with distribution $F$ won't be quite the same as this approximate median: it must lie somewhere between the $1/2-\alpha/2$ and $1/2+\alpha/2$ quantiles.  In the present case, where $F$ is nonzero in a neighborhood of its median, this means that by taking $\alpha$ sufficiently small (but still nonzero), we can make the median of $F_\alpha$ as close as we like to the median of $F=F_0.$

It remains only to find the mean of $F_\alpha$ in the question, where $F$ is the half-Cauchy distribution determined by

$$F(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^x \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2} = \frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(x)$$

for $x\ge 0.$

The ensuing calculations are straightforward.  First,

$$E_\alpha = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \frac{x\,\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{\pi(1-\alpha)} \log\frac{1+x_1^2}{1+x_0^2}$$

where $F(x_0) = \alpha/2$ and $F(x_1) = 1-\alpha/2.$  Thus

$$x_0 = \tan\left(\frac{\pi\alpha}{4}\right) \approx \frac{\pi\alpha}{4},\quad x_1 = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi\alpha}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{x_0} \approx \frac{4}{\pi\alpha},$$

whence

$$E_\alpha \approx \frac{1}{\pi} \log \frac{1 + \left(\frac{4}{\pi\alpha}\right)^2}{1 + \left(\frac{\pi\alpha}{4}\right)^2} \approx \frac{2}{\pi}\log\left(\frac{4}{\pi\alpha}\right).$$

Finally, when taking a sample of size $n$ from $F$ we would like to ensure that *most of the time* the sample really is a sample of $F_\alpha,$ uncontaminated by any values in its tails.  This happens with probability $(1-\alpha)^n.$  To make this chance exceed some threshold $1-\epsilon,$ with a tiny value of $\epsilon,$ we must have

$$\alpha \approx \frac{\epsilon}{n}.$$

Using this value in the foregoing gives

$$E_\alpha \approx \frac{2}{\pi}\log\left(\frac{4}{\pi\epsilon/n}\right) = \frac{2}{\pi}\left(\log\left(\frac{4}{\pi\epsilon}\right) + \log(n)\right).$$

Consequently, the median of the sum of $n$ *iid* half-Cauchy variables must be close to

$$nE_\alpha \approx \frac{2}{\pi}n\log(n) +  \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\log\frac{4}{\pi\epsilon}\right)n.$$

For any desired $\epsilon\gt 0,$ we may choose $n$ so large that the value is dominated by the first term: that is how the $n\log n$ behavior arises.  Moreover, now we have the implicit constant $2/\pi$ along with the asymptotic order of the error term, $O(n).$

Let the "relative median" be $nE_\alpha$ divided by $\left(2/\pi\right) n\log(n).$ Here is a plot of such relative medians as observed in 5,000 simulations of samples up to size 5,000.  The reference red curve is a multiple of $1/\log(n),$ which this analysis indicates is proportional to the asymptotic relative error.  The fit is good.

[image: Figure]

The `R` code to produce it can be used for additional simulation studies.

```R
n.sim <- 5e3  # Simulation count
n <- 5e3      # Maximum sample size
X <- apply(apply(matrix(abs(rt(n*n.sim, 1)), n), 2, cumsum), 1, median)

N <- seq_len(n)[-1]        # Can't divide by n log(n) when n==0
X <- X[-1]
x.0 <- 2/pi * N * log(N)   # Theory
#
# Plot the relative medians.
#
plot(N, X / x.0, xlab="n", log="xy", cex=0.5, pch=19,
     ylab="Value",
     main="Simulated Relative Medians")
#
# Draw a reference curve.
#
fit <- lm(X / x.0 - 1 ~ 0 + I(1/log(N)))
summary(fit)
b <- coefficients(fit)[1]
curve(1 + b/log(n) , add=TRUE, xname="n", lwd=2, col="Red")
```

Comment: Your arguments and mine lead to similar integrals here. My informal statements of $x \sim y$ seem to correspond roughly to your statements of $P[|x-y| < O(n)]<\epsilon$, and I’m glad to see now how your more formal approach works in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to estimate the median in the question, using order statistics:
\begin{align}
\text{median}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|X|_i\right)
&=\text{median}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|X|_{(i)}\right) && (1)\\
&\sim\sum_{i=1}^n\text{median}\left(|X|_{(i)}\right) && (2)\\
&\sim\sum_{i=1}^n F_{|X|}^{-1}\left(\frac{i}{n+1}\right) && (3)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n F_{X}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2n+2}\right) &&\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \tan\left(\frac{\pi i}{2n+2}\right)  && \\
&\sim \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x=i-1/2}^{i+1/2} \tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2n+2}\right)dx && (4)\\
&=\int_{x=1/2}^{n+1/2} \tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2n+2}\right)dx && \\
&=\frac{2n+2}{\pi}\log\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4n+4}\right)\right) && (5)\\
\end{align}

- In (1), we wrote the sum as the sum of order statistics.
- In (2), we replaced the median of the sum by the sum of the medians, which is the most questionable part of this estimate.
- In (3), we used the standard estimate for the central value of an order statistic.
- In (4), we estimated a tangent as the average of nearby tangents.
- In (5), the cotangent of small $x$ is like $1/x$, so we could also write the final result as $O(n \log n)$, as predicted in the comments above.